# How do I use a custom LateX package?

Tags: macros

I want to draw some Signal Processing plots in my document, and found a package called dsptricks on ctan. I downloaded the .sty files, copied them to /usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/dsp_stuff, but am now stuck. What do I do next, how do I make TeX find the .sty files in dsp_stuff?

Comment: You have to run texhash, I think. On the other hand, put the `.sty` file in the same folder as your `.tex` file.

Comment: First you should put them in your local texmf folder. (See linked duplicate) But this package is already part of TeX Live so in principle you should not need to install it manually.